# Why do Python's match statements not raise an Exception when no pattern matches?

Tags: python, python-3.10

[PEP 634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/) and [PEP 635](https://peps.python.org/pep-0635/) introduce *structural pattern matching*. But no rationale is given why nothing happens, if none of the patterns matches:

```py
var = 3
match var:
    case 1:
        pass
    case 2:
        pass

print("End is reached without Exception.")
```

From Erlang i am used to this raising an Exception. In Rust, this would not compile. In Python you always have to add an *irrefutable pattern*:

```py
    case _:
        raise Exception("…")
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because python is not a functional programming language. FP also often require pairing of if and else, but these are generally not restricted in imperative programming languages.

Comment: To clarify, you do not "always have to" add an irrefutable pattern. If none matches and there is no irrefutable pattern, it executes the code under the `match` block.

Comment: Why does `if x == 1: foo()` not raise an exception for `x = 2`, even if there is no `else` clause? Why should pattern matching do?

Comment: Very true @STerliakov

Answer (score 0):

The Python match statement evaluates the value after the match keyword and checks it against the pattern (the code next to case). If there’s a match, the statements inside the case block will be executed with the bound variables. If there’s no match, nothing happens and the next statement is executed. If there's no match at all and no irrefutable pattern, `None` is returned as can be seen in the example below:

```
def match_case(var=3):
    match var:
        case 1:
            return 1
        case 2:
            return 2

print(match_case())
```

So yes, nothing seems to happen but it actually returns `None`. It wouldn't raise an Exception because this is not considered an Exception by the interpreter.

Furthermore, it is not compulsory to add the wildcard pattern i.e. `case _`.
According to [PEP634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/)

> A pattern is considered irrefutable if we can prove from its syntax alone that it will always succeed. In particular, capture patterns and wildcard patterns are irrefutable.

This does not suggest that one must include the wildcard pattern, rather it says that the wildcard pattern never fails to succeed if included.

Comment: Returning `None` is the default behavior in the [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), which is not directly related to the absence of irrefutable pattern.

Comment: @MechanicPig True and that was specific to my use case here (used in a function). The succeeding statements then addressed the OP's question on why it does nothing and if a wildcard must be used in python.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Python docs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-a-wildcard), "You may want to print an error message saying that the command wasn’t recognized when all the patterns fail. You could use the feature we just learned and write case [*ignored_words] as your last pattern."

Therefore, something like this can work

```py
var = 3
match var:
    case 1:
        pass
    case 2:
        pass
    ....

    case _:
       # throw your error here
       pass
```

In this case if no number matches, the exception will be raised in the case with the  '_' wildcard.

Comment: I do not think that this answers the OP's question. OP is basically asking why the python interpreter does nothing if all other patterns fail. He also asked why *"In Python you always have to add an irrefutable pattern"* which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got to understand it the wrong